# Bulk mailing to a group has no recipients

Tags: civimail

I'm trying to send a mass emailing to a group I have set up.  When I put the group into the mailing, it shows that there are no recipients even though there should be hundreds.  I have found that if I tick the "Bulk mailings?" option next to an individual's email address, they're then part of the recipients.  Is there a way to check this box for everyone, or is there some other thing I can do?

I did try "update civicrm_email set is_bulkmail=1" and although all the records were changed, they're still not included in the mailings.  Now I find that if I "edit" a record, do nothing, then "save", they're suddenly included in the mailing.

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: Do you have `is_primary` set on any of the emails in civicrm_email table? Specifically for the recipients?

Comment: If you're going to make bulk changes like that, you're better doing it with the API than direct SQL.  There are dependencies between fields that API updates will take care of and avoid some issues like this.  (Not saying this was caused by doing SQL updates, but possible.)